# `s` becomes empty after assignment

Tags: javascript, typescript

For the following code, `s` becomes empty after assignment.  I treat `s` as a global variable for usage within the anonymous function. But seems like it is now. How is it work?

```
 var s = "";

    Utility.readAllFiles('testth/expression', function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(results);
        s += results.join(",");//s is non-empty here
    });



    res.end(s + "\n\n\n");//s is empty here
```

Comment: This is _asynchronous_, your `res.end(s ...` is triggered _before_ the call**back** of your `readAllFiles` is triggered, therefor the `s` is empty. Please search for asynchronous javascript, theres tons of questions on SO about it already.

Comment: Move `res.end(s...` statement inside the `readAllFiles` callback.